# IIS Express w/ VS 2022 crashes when debugging web app and selecting file via file html input on page w/ ExtJs

Tags: visual-studio-2019, iis-express, visual-studio-2022, extjs6-classic

Here are the details:

- OS: Windows 2016 server accessed over RD
- Dev tools: VS 2022 17.1.6 & VS 2019 16.11.11. I run VS in Admin mode (both)
- IIS Express version: 10.0.22489.1000, 64 bit
- Browser Chrome: 100.0.4896.127 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- App:.net 4 webforms application that uses ExtJs 6.6.0 classic as front end
- Antivirus: CrowdStrike, version 6.36.15005.0.

I have a form with a [file](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.form.field.File.html) field. This [link](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.6.0/classic/Ext.form.Basic.html#method-hasUpload) has more information on how the upload works, it basically uses an iframe under the hood.

Now, in VS 2019 the upload works. In VS 2022 the upload doesn't work anymore and it returns the error: "Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:38991" from accessing a cross-origin frame." (the error is returned in the client JavaScript code). Just to be clear, I open exactly the same project in VS 2019 and it works, then I open the project in VS 2022 and the uploads don't work anymore.

Both use the same IIS Express process (64 bit). And one minor detail, the upload operation when run from VS 2022 kills IIS Express, it basically evaporates.

Any idea on how to fix this in VS 2022? For now, I have to use VS 2019 in order to be able to test uploads.

Thanks in advance.

Update:
I installed VS 2022 version 17.1.6.

Initially I thought IIS express evaporates upon uploading the file. It actually exits when I select the file in the Open dialog.

`The program '[19000] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff).`

When I run the project without debugging, it works fine!

I changed the title of the post from:

`ExtJs file upload getting: "Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:38991" from accessing a cross-origin frame." when run w/ VS 2022 IIS Express`

to

`IIS Express w/ VS 2022 crashes when debugging web app and selecting file via file html input on page w/ ExtJs`

Answer (score 7):

ok, found the answer here: [IIS Express stops suddenly when I click on a text box in my web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50377950/iis-express-stops-suddenly-when-i-click-on-a-text-box-in-my-web-app).

This did the trick:
[image]

The checkbox was clear in VS 2019, a colleague confirmed the uploads work in VS 2019 even with the checkbox selected.