# IIS Express in visual studio 2017 crashes when debugging app and selecting file input

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web, visual-studio-2017, iis-express

I have a form with a file field.
In VS 2017 the upload doesn’t work and it returns the error: "The program '[19000] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff)."
The upload operation when run from kills IIS Express, it basically evaporates. Any idea on how to fix this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IIS Express stops suddenly when I click on a text box in my web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50377950/iis-express-stops-suddenly-when-i-click-on-a-text-box-in-my-web-app)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

ok, found the answer here: [IIS Express stops suddenly when I click on a text box in my web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50377950/iis-express-stops-suddenly-when-i-click-on-a-text-box-in-my-web-app).

This did the trick:
[image]

The checkbox was clear in VS 2017.

Comment: Good catch. Took me forever to figure out what was happening here.